# Parse.com API create object with file

Tags: parse-platform, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to use Appcelerator Titanium with Parse.com service. Since there is no library for Titanium, I'm using the rest API of Parse.

A Class object on Parse can have a field of type "File". How do I post a file (blob object) to that field?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starter template application for using Parse with Appcelerator

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/parse-starter-appC

it wraps the parse API in a appcelerator alloy sync adapter

A helper method with allow you to upload the file and associate it with a specific object called a `FileHelper`. This `FileHelper` object will provide access to the image

```
var parseService = require('parseREST');
parseService.init();

file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "iTunesConnect.png");
var blob = file.read();

parseService.uploadFile("image/jpeg", "iTunesConnect.png", blob).then(function(_results) {
    return parseService.createObject('FileHelper', {
        "nameKey" : _results.response.name,
        "fileData" : {
            "name" : _results.response.name,
            "__type" : "File"
        }
}).then(function(_results2) {
    console.log("FileHelper Object: " + JSON.stringify(_results2));
},function(_error)
    console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(_error));
});
```

The results should look something like this:

```
{
    "createdAt": "2015-05-11T15:30:52.004Z",
    "objectId": "yLPdeXDinq"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. tried the example from the repository readme - but it's not working. TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'parseService.init({

Comment: ok. figured it out. but now for every request I get "ParseClient Missing Credentials" - I gave it the correct API key and ID

Comment: I fixed the problem in your source but no authorised to push the change. I think it has potential but lacks documentation. Also, errors recived from callbacks are not clear. Making it impossible to work with and pretty much useless. Will definitely check it again in the future to see if it had improved. thanks.

Comment: sorry it was not useful for you, I am using that exact library on a project now and it was used by others already... Don't know about "useless" but I have seen your comments in the past so I will take that with a grain of salt... best of luck, sorry I bothered you.

Comment: I only know github from projects I publish. how can I push changes to your project? I would like to try and help improve the module - I think it has a potential since there it is currently the most relevant Parse project there is.

Comment: i don't know why you down-voted the solution that is working or because you did not think there was sufficient documentation. It is not the objective of stack overflow, IMHO, to simply provide you with cut-and-paste solutions to development, but more of guidance to a solution. I stand behind my commitment  to helping people and my reputation demonstrates that

Comment: It is not working. Take the solution to a new project - and it is not working. There are bugs in the code - which I offered to fix (btw - after fixing I found even more). I was not expecting a simple copy&paste I was expecting an answer to the question above - which this answer did not supply. Sorry.